# NullPointerException when creating an ArrayList-like class

Tags: java, junit, arraylist, abstract

As a practice exercise, I am creating my own generic class that is basically a copy of `ArrayList`. While testing the class with `JUnit`, I come across a `NullPointerException` error in the add method:

```
public void add(int index, T element) {
    if (index > this.size() || index < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    if (this.size() == data.length) {
        // ^ This is the line that the error points to
        resize(this.data);
    }

    for (int i = index; i < this.size; i++) {
        this.data[i + 1] = this.data[i]; //fix
    }

    this.data[index] = element;
    size++;
}
```

After messing around with the class a lot, I can't figure out where the error is coming from. I can provide any details/other parts of the class that are needed.  Any guidance as to where the problem is located would be fantastic.  Thank You.

The constructor for the class:

```
MyArrayList(int startSize) {
    // round the startSize to nearest power of 2
    int pow2 = 1;
    do {
        pow2 *= 2;
    } while (pow2 < startSize);

    startSize = pow2;
    this.size = 0;
    T[] data = (T[]) new Object[startSize];
}
```

The following test case tests the size, but encounters the error when it tries to add an element:

```
public void testSize() {
    MyArrayList<Integer> test = new MyArrayList<Integer>(); 
    ArrayList<Integer> real = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    assertEquals("Size after construction", real.size(), test.size());
    test.add(0,5);
    real.add(0,5);
    assertEquals("Size after add", real.size(), test.size());
}
```

Comment: Well, `this` can't be `null`, so `data` must be, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
T[] data = (T[]) new Object[startSize];
```

That initializes the local variable `data`. Which you don't want.

Change it to following to make sure that you initialize the instance variable -

```
this.data = (T[]) new Object[startSize];
```

Comment: +1 This is when it pays to turn on (and pay attention to) warnings about unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

I the NPE is on the line you have mentioned it is only because `data` is `null`. Where are you initialyzing `data` ?

Maybe when you are creating your `CustomArrayList` you are not initialyzing your internal array `data`.

The `data` intialisation is the problem. It should be 
`this.data = (T[])new Object[startSize];`

Comment: The data is in the constructor, I edited the original post to add in the constructor

Comment: can you post your contructor and also the test case?